# How to hide views page title

Tags: views

I need to hide the page title in Views but still have it appear as the page title on the browser's window tab (for SEO). Could someone help me with that? I've looked around many times for answers but I haven't had any luck yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like something that should be pretty easy to do with a CSS selector. The user won't see the title but all functionality outside of seeing it on the page will still work.

More specifically, you could add a rule to your css file like:

```
#page-title {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: but that's going to affect ALL views... what if I just want a specific views not to show the title?

Comment: Each page has a class associated with it attached to the body tag, think the css class is based on the url. So for a page with url http://mysite.com/mypage you could make your CSS selector more specific like: `body.page-mypage #page-title { display:none };`

Answer (score 3):

The CSS solution might not be the best for SEO purposes... 
Another better alternative is to write in the page title field :

```
<No Title> 
or : to leave it blank
```

And the title wont be displayed

Comment: This will disable the title tag as well, so I can't tell what's worst.

Comment: This is the best and easiest solution by far...I'm perplexed as to why others are even trying other solutions...

Answer (score -1):

```
function module_block_view_alter(&$data, $block){
    if($block->delta == 'your view name or id'){
        $data['title'] = 'my new title';
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

unset the title in page preprocess hook

Comment: My experience has been that unsetting the title with the preprocess hook unsets all instances of the title and thus the page behaves as if there's no title at all so meta data is affected.